Is it possible that classical propagator be used as an integrating factor for solving differential equations?
I have two questions about the picture.
1)
I think classical propagator itself is not function, is just an operator.
And "(operator)(function)" is not that "(operator)X(function)".
So it seems that the product rule can't be applied in differentiation.
Then, is it possible that classical propagator be used as an integrating factor for solving differential equations?
2)
The first term in the differential equation is partial derivative.
Then, is it possible to integrate both sides with respect to x ("dx") while solving a differential equation using integrating factor?
?)


isn't this just a type of Green's function?

I'm answering, assuming $L_0$ is a scalar.
Integration in space

Then, is it possible to integrate both sides with respect to x ("dx") while solving a differential equation using integrating factor?

If you perform this operation, you're integrating over the space variable and thus computing a multiple of the average field $\int_x f(x,t) dx = L \overline{f}(t)$, without solving the evolution in time. Thus, you'd get a dynamical equation for the average value of the function: you're losing the information on the point value of $f(x,t)$ and not solving the evolution in time. You can do it, but I'm not sure this is what you want.
Integration in time
The solution of the linear equation is the convolution (not the "usual" product) of the "impulsive response" (the propagator) and the forcing term in time domain, and the product of the transforms in transformed domains (here Laplace). You can prove it both in time and transformed domains.
Time domain. Starting from the equation
$$\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + i L_0 \right) \Delta f(x,t) = - i \Delta L(t) F(x) \ ,$$
you can multiply by $e^{i L_0 t}$ in order to get
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left( e^{i L_0 t} \Delta f(x,t) \right) =  e^{i L_0 t} \left( -i \Delta L(t) F(x) \right) \ ,$$
that, after integration in time, becomes
$$e^{i L_0 t} \Delta f(x,t) - e^{i L_0 t_0} \Delta f(x,t_0) = \int_{\tau=t_0}^t  e^{i L_0 \tau} \left( -i \Delta L(\tau) F(x) \right) d \tau$$
$$\Delta f(x,t) = e^{i L_0 (t_0 - t)} \Delta f(x,t_0) + \int_{\tau=t_0}^t  e^{i L_0 (\tau - t)} \left( -i \Delta L(\tau) F(x) \right) d \tau$$
Laplace domains.
$$s\Delta \hat{f}(x,s) - \Delta \hat{f}(x,0) + i L_0 \Delta \hat{f}(x,s) = - i \Delta \hat{L}(s) F(x)$$
$$\hat{f}(x,s) = \frac{1}{s + i L_0} \Delta \hat{f}(x,0) +\frac{1}{s + i L_0} (-i \Delta \hat{L}(s) F(x)) \ .$$
